# Timeout connecting from Heroku to AWS RDS Aurora instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-rds, knex.js, amazon-aurora

I need to connect a Node.js app running on Heroku  to an Aurora instance running inside AWS RDS.

The connection is working just fine on my local machine, but on Heroku the **it's timing out** (`Error: timeout expired` from `pg/lib/client.js` ).

My configuration overview:

- `nodejs@14`
- `knex@0.21.18`
- `pg@8.6.0`
- Aurora instance is running in `eu-west-1`
- I am using Heroku hobby tier dynos (development environment)

Things I have tried:

1. I have checked my VPC ACL configuration (it looks fully open to me):
   [image: VPC ACL configuration inbound rules]
2. I have explicitly provided the RDS AWS certificate authority certificate in connection configuration (from here: [Using SSL/TLS to encrypt a connection to a DB cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html)) - didn't help.

3. I have tried connecting to a Heroku Postgres instance using the same configuration, it worked just fine.

Comment: What about the security group attached to the RDS cluster?

Comment: @MarkB Thanks for the comment, it pointed me into the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that even if you select the "enable public access" option when creating a VPC for an RDS instance, AWS by default **only whitelists your IP** in the Security Group settings.

I have added the following inbound rule to the security group, and it worked!
[image]

Comment: Enable public access gives the server a public IP address. Without enabling that, the server would only have a private IP address that works inside your VPC.